# Magento 2: Product page price label ($10.10-$70.0)

Tags: product-page

Magneto 2 product page price labels this type as soon as($10.0-70.0) https://prnt.sc/olzchv

Comment: screen shot not loading.

Comment: Please check agian

Comment: try with str_replace()

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
<?php $maxprice = str_replace("$"," ",$regularPrice->getMaxRegularAmount());
            echo $regularPrice->getMinRegularAmount().'-'.$maxprice;
?>
```

OR

```
    <?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $currency = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency');
        $price = $regularPrice->getMaxRegularAmount();
        $maxprice =  $currency->format($price, ['display'=>\Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL], false);

echo $regularPrice->getMinRegularAmount().'-'.$maxprice;
        ?>
```

**i hope its work for you**

Comment: plz send the  file path

Comment: app/design/frontend/theme/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml - debug this file.